# Intellij idea triggered brakepoint without having one

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I faced a strange problem while debugging my project. The problem is that Idea triggered a breakpoint at the lines where no any breakpoints actually. However, breakpoints have been set at that lines before, but not now. Any advices?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEadw.png) attached.

Comment: Do you use remote debugging? If you do, it looks like your source code is not in sync with your binaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584026/how-to-remove-phantom-breakpoints-pointing-to-old-missing-source-from-intellij/35588829#35588829

Comment: Did you tried ctrl+F8 (in Linux and windows). There you can see all the breakpoints. And like Vladimir Vagaytsev said, do you use a remote debugger? if so try to redeploy your code to sync it.

Comment: It is local debugging. I have look for all breakpoints list but there are only explicit ones.